# Inno Setup 5.5.4(a) under Windows 7 with mistake "cannot import dll"

Tags: windows-7, inno-setup, dllimport

I need to do one serup application with couple of dll's:
In the pas-script do used compinstkey.dll which call the aspr_ide.dll.
I did in the iss-script:

```
[Files]
Source: aspr_ide.dll; DestDir: {app};Flags: ignoreversion
Source: CompInstKey.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
....
[Code]
....
function GetRegistrationKeys: PAnsiChar;
external 'GetRegistrationKeys@files:aspr_ide.dll stdcall';

procedure Installinfo(ApplicationName, Version, UserName, Key: PAnsiChar);
  external 'Installinfo@files:CompInstKey.dll stdcall';
....
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;

begin
 Result := False;
 ExtractTemporaryFile('aspr_ide.dll');
 ExtractTemporaryFile('CompInstKey.dll');
end;
.....
```

in the Windows XP it work fine, but Windows7 do throw the error "Cannot import dll: C:...\Temp\tp.GHPtmp\aspr_ide.dll". At the pause of installation the aspr_ide.dll in this moment exist at the "C:...\Temp\tp.GHPtmp\".

What do I wrong? Why dont run under Windows 7? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `delayload` keyword on your function declarations like:

```
function GetRegistrationKeys: PAnsiChar;
external 'GetRegistrationKeys@files:aspr_ide.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure Installinfo(ApplicationName, Version, UserName, Key: PAnsiChar);
  external 'Installinfo@files:CompInstKey.dll stdcall delayload';
```

The delayload causes the setup to only load the DLL when it is called rather than at startup as documented at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you update Inno to version 5.5.9, which has the fewest bugs. Second, recompile the DLL on the Win7 system because DLLs may not be the same in the XP and Win7 dependent dynamic libraries.